# Windows 10 - Skip "Sign In" button when switching between two passwordless local accounts

Tags: windows-10, login-screen

I have the following situation:

- Headless Windows 10 Home desktop
- Two local accounts without passwords

When I attempt to switch between the users, Windows returns me to the sign in screen and asks me to click Sign In. The system has no devices connected that can be used to activate the button (no keyboard, mouse, etc.). The "NoLockScreen" registry entry does not change this behavior.

Is there a way to force Windows to automatically log in the user being switched to, without the splash screen?

Any applicable solution is appropriate - registry changes, third-party applications, PowerShell script.

Edited to add requested screenshot, this is the screen I'm getting:

[image]

Desired behavior is to immediately show the next user's desktop, with no interactive screen beforehand.

Comment: What screen are you expecting exactly? Can you provide a screenshot of the exact screen you are getting.

Comment: @Ramhound - Screenshot added to the post. Desired behavior is to immediately show the next user's desktop, with no confirmation. So, switch user -> choose next username -> next screen should be that user's desktop, separated by only a non-interactive loading screen.

Comment: So you want the list of users that exist on the machine.  So you want the logon screen to be displayed? In order to switch the user, you have to interact in some way, specifically to choose which user you want to log into.

Comment: @Ramhound - I'm specifically looking for a way to execute a user switch that does not require confirming on the logon screen. If user 1 is logged in, and initiates a switch to user 2, the switch should occur without needing to specifically hit "sign in".

Comment: That doesn’t exist in any version of Windows